# TextView android:autoLink attribute recognize IP address pattern unexpectly

Tags: android, attributes, textview, ip-address

Set

```
android:autoLink="web"
```

work fine for me.

However, the system even recognize the pattern that there are 4 numbers with 3 dots like

```
2.5.3.6
```

as url.

That's true, it really is IP address pattern but I do not want these text to be highlighted because it is just the plain text happen to look like IP address.

How can I prevent this except there really is a "http://" prefix next to this pattern?

Answer (score 0):

This should help you: **[Remove Underline from Android TextView Link](http://www.evilcodingmonkey.com/2011/06/07/remove-underline-from-android-textview-link/)**

If you want to change the color of the IP Address, I recommend to set the color of the TextView after its text is "unspanned".

Comment: Interesting topic. But I do not need it. By now, I can think of making use of Linkify class and define my own regular expression.